# foreach($item) limit number by category

Tags: php, foreach, limit

I'm trying to limit number of items in a portfolio script.

```
  <?php
    $k = 1;     
    shuffle($items);
    foreach ($items as $item ){ 
    if($k==11) break; ?>
    <li data-id="id-<?php echo($k);  ?>" data-type="<?php echo( ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $item->item_category) ); ?>">
    ..........more item listings ....
    </li>
    <?php $k++; }   ?>
```

I've added shuffle to the code, so I get different results from different categories and I can limit the overall number of results. But how could I limit the number of items per category? Like getting 5 items from each category and then shuffle them?

I cannot change overall functions, because it's part of a plugin. Yet some changes added to code is possible. Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Comment: you can use `arrays` and `count()` for such deal.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to fetch 5 of each items *before* reuniting and shuffling them.

Comment: Hm, it would, but I'm rather new to php, and don't have ideas how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't limit the number of items per category in the incoming data, then you need a data structure to count them as they're input:

```
<?php
$k = 1;
$max_per_category = 5;
$cat_tracker = array();

shuffle($items);

foreach ($items as $item ){ 
    if( $k >= 11 ) {
        break;
    }

    if( ! isset($cat_tracker[$item->item_category]) ) {
        $cat_tracker[$item->item_category] = 1;
    } else if( $cat_tracker[$item->item_category] >= $max_per_category ) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $cat_tracker[$item->item_category]++;
    }

    $frame = '<li data-id="id-%d" data-type="%s">';
    printf($frame, $k, ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $item->item_category));
    // more item listings?
    printf('</li>');

    $k++;
}
```

I've also replaced your output code with something cleaner. Dropping in and out of PHP like that is difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: about to try this one too.

Comment: I get an unespected { error on this line      if( ! isset($cat_tracker[$item->item_category] ) {

:(

Comment: @MajaMiljković missed a closing bracket on the `if()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use for instead of foreach

```
<?php
    $values = shuffle($items);
    for ($k=0 ;$items[k] && $k<11;$k++ ){ 
    >
    <li data-id="id-<?php echo($k);  ?>" data-type="<?php echo( ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $items[$k]->item_category) ); ?>">
    ..........more item listings ....
    </li>
    <?
}   

?>
```

Comment: I've tried the code, now need to implement it with the rest. It does the filtering, but the images don't show up.

Comment: Had to omit this solution, since $k is used by other elements also, when I changed it into something else, it didn't do the sorting, when it did, the images did not show up. but it worked with simplified code when I removed other elements.

Comment: You can use another variable $i, and affect him the value of $k if necessary.
$i = $k;